# Why are there so many different vector and parametric equations for a line?

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

Please explain why there are many different vector and parametric equations for a line.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a parametric curve. If you have another function $f:[c,d] \to [a,b]$ that is *increasing* and bijective (a.k.a. order isomorphism), the composition $\gamma \circ f = \gamma(f(t))$ would be another parametrisation of the same curve.